# Grep multiple expressions in one pass, output matches to each expression in separate file

Tags: linux, grep

I want to use `grep` on the `top` utility.  Iterating through `top` 5 times, here are my criteria:

- `grep` two different expressions in a single pass on the `top` output
- expression 1: `grep` for the line on overall cpu usage, then output it to file: ***cpu_stats.txt***
- expression 2: `grep` for the line on overall memory usage, then output it to file: ***memory_stats.txt***

Here is what I have now:

```
top -b -n 5 | egrep "\%Cpu\(s\):|KiB Mem :" > both_cpu_and_memory.txt
```

This successfully grabs the desired `top` output, but notice it is putting both expression matches in the exact same file.

Where I am stuck: I do not know how to, in a single pass, output the matches from one expression to one file, and how to output the matches from the *other* expression to *another* file.

Is this possible?  Is it possible to, in one pass, grep multiple expressions, and matches for each expression is outputted to a separate file?

Comment: This is more a job for `awk`.

Comment: @Shawn according to this: grep is faster: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88503/using-grep-vs-awk

Comment: ... so? You're not exactly scanning a lot of data.

Comment: @Shawn this is a valid point.  Nevertheless: if one solution is more performant, I'd prefer to go with that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you do something convoluted with saving the output in a temporary file and making a couple of passes over it, you can't do what you want with `grep`. It's really easy with `awk`, though:

```
top -b -n 5 | awk '/%Cpu\(s\):/ { print > "cpu_stats.txt" }
                   /KiB Mem :/  { print > "memory_stats.txt" }'
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` cannot do what you ask.  This is a job for `awk`, or indeed *any* other scripting language capable of parsing or capable of using regular expressions.